# Why is my 3D to 2D image transformation result different from Blender's?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, blender, coordinate-transformation

In my simulation a 3D point needs to be transformed to a fisheye image equivalent of Blender's PANO camera with equidistant camera model. Where can I find scientific papers and technical reports of Blender's implementation of the 3D to 2D transformation?

I'm looking for:

1. Transformation from world to camera coordinate system.
2. Transformation from camera coordinate system (cartesian) to camera coordinate system (spherical) for projection of the point to unit sphere before projecting the point onto the image plane.
3. Transformation from spherical camera coordinate system to sensor plane.
4. Normalization of shifting the point from principal point to the left top corner of the sensor.

While implementation from perspective camera is available in bpy_extras module, transformation for equidistant camera model is not. My result is different from Blender, why?

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=4, suppress=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import plotting

def compute_R(alpha_deg, beta_deg, gamma_deg):
    ## Rotation Matrix R (code from CV2 exercise)

    # convert into radians...
    alpha = alpha_deg * np.pi / 180
    beta  = beta_deg  * np.pi / 180
    gamma = gamma_deg * np.pi / 180

    # prepare sine and cosine values
    ca = np.cos(alpha)
    sa = np.sin(alpha)
    cb = np.cos(beta)
    sb = np.sin(beta)
    cg = np.cos(gamma)
    sg = np.sin(gamma)
    
    # rotation about x axis
    R_x = np.array([
        [1,  0,   0],
        [0, ca, -sa],
        [0, sa,  ca],
    ], dtype=float)

    # rotation about y axis
    R_y = np.array([
        [ cb, 0, sb],
        [  0, 1,  0],
        [-sb, 0, cb]    
    ], dtype=float)

    # rotation about z axis
    R_z = np.array([
        [cg, -sg, 0],
        [sg,  cg, 0],
        [ 0,   0, 1]    
    ], dtype=float)

    # compose R_xyz
    R = R_z.dot(R_y.dot(R_x))
        
    return R

def cart2spherical_wiki(X_cam):
    ## from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system
    r = np.sqrt(X_cam[0]**2 + X_cam[1]**2 + X_cam[2]**2)
    print(f'manual_{r=}')
    #r = np.linalg.norm(X_cam, axis=0)
    #print(f'np.linalg_{r=}')
    theta = np.arccos(X_cam[2] / r)
    phi = -np.arctan2(X_cam[1], X_cam[0])

    return theta, phi

def cart2spherical_blender(X_cam, fov):
    # can be ignored for the moment
    r = np.arctan2(np.sqrt(X_cam[1] * X_cam[1] + X_cam[2] * X_cam[2]), X_cam[0]) / fov
    phi = np.arctan2(X_cam[2], X_cam[1])

    return r, phi

def spherical2normimg(f_x, f_y, theta, phi):
    # from phd-thesis michel
    x_img_norm = f_x * theta * np.cos(phi)
    y_img_norm = f_y * theta * np.sin(phi)
    #print(x_img_norm)
    #print(y_img_norm)

    return x_img_norm, y_img_norm

def spherical2normimg_blender(r, phi):
    # can be ignored for the moment
    x_img_norm = r * np.cos(phi) + 0.5
    y_img_norm = r * np.sin(phi) + 0.5

    return x_img_norm, y_img_norm

def points_to_image(x, y, resolution):
    
    # Sensorpunkt (0,0) liegt im Bild an Position (w/2, h/2)
    # deshalb Addition der halben Bildauflösung
    # (x,y) - Sensorpunkte
    # (x_new, y_new) - Bildpunkte
    x_new = x + resolution[0]//2
    y_new = y + resolution[1]//2

    return x_new, y_new

def main():
    # plot input/output?
    plot = 'True'
        
    ## World points
    X_wrld = np.array([
                    [1.5, 5, 1], # right foot
                    [2.5, 5, 1], # left foot
                    [2, 5, 3], # hip
                    [1, 5, 5], # right hand
                    [3, 5, 5]  # left hand
                    ])

    ## Camera
    C = np.array([2, 1, 4]).transpose() # camera projection center in world coordinates

    ## Plot World with 3D Points and Camera
    fig = plt.figure()
    if plot == 'True':
        title = 'World coordinate system: 3D Points and Camera'
        plt1 = plotting.plot_world(X_wrld, C, elev=0, azim=-90, roll=0, title=title, fig=fig)
    
    # transpose X_wrld
    X_wrld = X_wrld.T # take the transpose

    # add ones for homogenious representation
    row_ones = np.ones([1, X_wrld.shape[1]])
    X_wrld_hom = np.concatenate([X_wrld, row_ones], axis=0)
    #print(f'{X_wrld_hom=}')
    ## Use Rotation-Matrix and C for creating H-Matrix (Homography, 4x4)

    # orientation / rotation
    alpha_deg = 0 # first:  rotate about alpha degrees around the camera's x-axis
    beta_deg  = 270 # second: rotate about beta  degrees around the camera's y-axis
    gamma_deg = 0 # third:  rotate about gamma degrees around the camera's z-axis
    
    # Compute 3x3 Rotation Matrix
    R = compute_R(alpha_deg, beta_deg, gamma_deg)
    #print(f'{R=}')

    # Build H-Matrix (4x4)

    # RC ist 3x1
    RC = np.zeros([3,1])
    RC = R.dot(C)
    RC = RC.T
    H = np.column_stack( (R, -RC) )
    H = np.row_stack( (H, [0, 0, 0, 1]) )
    #print(f'{H=}')

    # Transformation from world to camera coordinates
    X_cam = H.dot(X_wrld_hom)
    print(f'{X_cam=}')

    if plot == 'True':
        title = f'camera coordinate system: camera rotation of {alpha_deg=}, {beta_deg=}, {gamma_deg=}'
        #plt2 = plotting.plot_camera(X_cam=X_cam.T, C=[0, 0, 0], elev=180, azim=90, roll=90, title=title, fig=fig)
        plt2 = plotting.plot_camera(X_cam=X_cam.T, C=[0, 0, 0], elev=alpha_deg, azim=beta_deg, roll=gamma_deg, title=title, fig=fig)
    
    ### Intrinsics ###
    # focal length from Canon FD 1:5,6 / 7,5mm (see, e.g. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischaugenobjektiv)
    f_mm = 0.0075 #7.5mm
    # field of view
    fov = 180 * np.pi / 180
    #  Vollformat Sensor, e.g. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Alpha_1
    chip_w = 35.7 * 1e-3 # 36mm
    chip_h = 23.8 * 1e-3 # 24mm
    # Resolution of camera
    res_w = 8640 # px
    res_h = 5760 # px
    # pixel densities
    m_x = res_w / chip_w # px/mm
    m_y = res_h / chip_h # px/mm
    # focal length normalized with pixel densities
    f_x = f_mm * m_x # unitless
    f_y = f_mm * m_y # unitless, f_x != f_y if pixel on the sensor is not square
    ### Intrinsics End ###

    ## From Camera coordinates (carthesian) to spherical camera coordinates (a) Wiki
    theta, phi = cart2spherical_wiki(X_cam)
    ## From spherical camera coordinates to normalized image coordinates (a) Wiki
    x_img_norm, y_img_norm = spherical2normimg(f_x, f_y, theta, phi)
    # camera to spherical from blender implementation
    #r, phi = cart2spherical_blender(X_cam, fov)
    # spherical to normalized image coordinates from blender code
    #x_img_norm, y_img_norm = spherical2normimg_blender(r, phi)

    if plot == 'True':
        title = 'Sensor coordinate system: Camera points on sensor plane'
        plt3 = plotting.plot_sensor(x_img_norm=x_img_norm, y_img_norm=y_img_norm, title=title, fig=fig)

    # From normalized image coordinates to image coordinates by shifting to left top of sensor
    x_img, y_img = points_to_image(x_img_norm, y_img_norm, (res_w, res_h))
    
    if plot == 'True':
        title = 'Image coordinate system: points on image plane shifted to left top corner'
        plotting.plot_image(x_img, y_img, (0, res_w), (0, res_h), title, fig)

    plt.show()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

plotting.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=4, suppress=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d


def plot_world(X_wrld, C, elev, azim, roll, title, fig):
    plt1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1, projection='3d')
    colors = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'm', 'y']
    labels = ['right foot', 'left foot', 'hip', 'right hand', 'left hand']    
    for X,Y,Z,c,l in zip(X_wrld[:,0], X_wrld[:,1], X_wrld[:,2], colors, labels):
        plt1.plot3D(X, Y, Z, c=c, marker=".", linestyle='None', label=l)
    
    plt1.plot3D(C[0], C[1], C[2], c="red", marker="v", linestyle='None', label="camera")
    plt1.set(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', zlabel='Z')
    plt1.set_xlim(0, 4)
    plt1.set_ylim(0, 6)
    plt1.set_zlim(0, 6)
    plt1.legend()
    plt1.set_title(title)
    plt1.view_init(elev=elev, azim=azim, roll=roll, vertical_axis='z')

    return plt1

def plot_camera(X_cam, C, elev, azim, roll, title, fig):
    plt2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2, projection='3d')
    colors = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'm', 'y']
    labels = ['right foot', 'left foot', 'hip', 'right hand', 'left hand']      
    for X,Y,Z,c,l in zip(X_cam[:,0], X_cam[:,1], X_cam[:,2], colors, labels):
        plt2.plot3D(X, Y, Z, c=c, marker=".", linestyle='None', label=l)
    
    plt2.plot3D(C[0], C[1], C[2], c="red", marker="v", linestyle='None', label="camera")
    plt2.set(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', zlabel='Z')
    plt2.legend()
    plt2.set_title(title)
    plt2.view_init(elev=elev, azim=azim, roll=roll, vertical_axis='z')

    return plt2

def plot_sensor(x_img_norm, y_img_norm, title, fig):
    plt3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
    colors = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'm', 'y']
    labels = ['right foot', 'left foot', 'hip', 'right hand', 'left hand']
    for x, y, c, l in zip(x_img_norm, y_img_norm, colors, labels):
        plt3.plot(x, y, c=c, marker=".", linestyle='None', label=l)
    
    plt3.set_title(title)
    return plt3

def plot_image(x_img_norm, y_img_norm, limit_x, limit_y, title, fig):
    plt4 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)
    colors = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'm', 'y']
    labels = ['right foot', 'left foot', 'hip', 'right hand', 'left hand']
    for x, y, c, l in zip(x_img_norm, y_img_norm, colors, labels):
        plt4.plot(x, y, marker='.', label= l, linestyle='None', c=c)

    plt4.set(xlim=limit_x, ylim=limit_y)
    plt4.set_title(title)
    plt4.legend()

    return plt4
```

[Blend-file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/280271/158481) where I tried to simulate same five points and render with equidistant camera. I tried different combinations of rotations (R_x, R_y, R_z). Compared to output from Blender, difference lies in reflection on vertical axis.

Answer (score 0):

To map from world to camera coordinates:

```
camera_obj = bpy.context.scene.camera
world_coords = ...
camera_coords = camera_obj.matrix_world.inverted() @ world_coords
```

Inspired by the source code for Cycles (`fisheye_to_direction()` and `direction_to_fisheye()` in https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/intern/cycles/kernel/camera/projection.h) we can map from camera space to final image coordinates:

```
camera = camera_obj.data
...
if camera.type == 'PANO':
    v = camera_coords
    a = v.x / v.z
    b = v.y / v.z

    r = math.atan(math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)) / camera.cycles.fisheye_fov / 0.5
    phi = math.atan2(v.y, v.x)
    x = r * math.cos(phi)
    y = r * math.sin(phi)

    # x and y are OpenGL style normalized device coordinates (-1,-1 is bottom left, 1,1 is top right)
    pixel_x = (0.5*v.x + 0.5) * scene.render.resolution_x
    pixel_y = (1 - (0.5*v.y + 0.5)) * scene.render.resolution_y
    ...
```